# For highstocks data grouping can you set data group points to null if there is less than a certain number of samples within it?

Tags: grouping, highcharts, nan

For example, if I have a data grouping level set to years and each year is composed of 365 values can I 'ignore' the years where I have less than 300 valid readings (such as NaN).

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The highcharts datagrouping group points by time not amount of points.

Docs:
- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping

Obviously you can prepare your own approximation function:
- http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.approximation

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand that the datagrouping is by time and not number of points. I was wondering if the number of points included in that time-frame is below a critical amount then is it possible to not display that group. Thanks again!